# Pi zero W 2 - bringing back from dead

Tags: boot

i had for a long time dead RPI Zero 2 Wifi, and i did a few modifications - soldered pins to I2C, +5V and GND, and put a mini RF connector for pigtail antenna. Tried overclocking it.

However Pi got dead. and i cannot for love of god understand what happened.

Since that i cleared all my modifications and checked there are no shorts on PCB, debree that is shorting anything (even in SD card connnector) etc...

From what i am able to tell, 5V and 3V3 rails are ok, what i am worried is 1V8 shows 1.05V and DDR_1V2 reads same - 1.05V. Core is 1.23V. The LED never goes on (with or without SD card) and no screen from HDMI either.

My other Pi02W has the 1.8V indeed at 1.8V ,DDR2 at 1.26V and core at 1.4V.

Is there some schematics of Pi, or can someone pinpoint to what can be the culprit? I still somehow believe it can be saved, with ... unability to get new one.

Comment: "Overclocking it" ....

Comment: AFAIK, there are no complete schematics. In fact, there have been comments made on RPI'S GitHub Docs repo that they may remove the current, partial schematics. IMHO, this is an abysmal practice - the fact that others have concluded the same accounts for the growing impetus for [Right to Repair Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_repair).

Comment: @MatsK: Doesn't the RPi Zero have the same closed-loop thermal control system as other Pis? Your assessment may be correct, but when I read it, I wondered why the in-built thermal control firmware allowed this to happen... any thoughts?

Comment: "Overclocking it" was a minor performance boost (i think 1.2 or 1.3GHz) since it was running a Chromium dashboard in kiosk mode for ... lets say weeks. It needed bit of push, but nothing horrendous, with proper heatsink and fan blowing on it. What i suspect might happen was some kind of power surge over supply line, or some electronic failed... I do push my Pi's little bit and all of them are running happily. What i was most afraid of was the WiFi modification, but i did same on other Pi (Pi 3A+) and it is running till this day no problem. ...

Answer (score 0):

The processor manufacturers place limits(specifications) on the part such as clock speed, pin current, etc. They make those specifications generally with some guard-band but that is for them to be sure to pass there specifications, nothing more. You will also note there warranties state these must not be exceeded or absolute max. They also tell you not to exceed these values with good reason as it may damage the chip. Therefore when operating outside their specifications the risk is yours. This is because chips even on the same wafer have variations. Sometimes you get lucky sometimes you do not, it is like throwing the dice, you never know.